# Mongodb querying - How to specify index traversal order?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

**Context**

I have a `users` collection with an array of key-value pairs like so:

```
{
  name: 'David',
  customFields: [
    { key: 'position', value: 'manager' },
    { key: 'department', value: 'HR' }
  ]
},

{
  name: 'Allison',
  customFields: [
    { key: 'position', value: 'employee' },
    { key: 'department', value: 'IT' }
  ]
}
```

The field names in `customFields` are configurable by the application users, so in order for it to be indexable I store them as an array of key-value pairs. Index `{ 'customFields.key': 1, 'customFields.value': 1}` works quite well. Problem is when I want to retrieve the results in either order (ascending or descending). Say I want to sort all users having the custom field `position` in either order. The below query gives me ascending order:

```
db.users.find({ customFields: { $elemMatch: { key: 'position' } } })
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to get the opposite order. I'm pretty sure with the way the indexes are structured, if I could tell mongodb to traverse the index backwards I would get what I want. The other options is to have an other 2 indexes to cover both directions, however it's more costly.

Is there a way to specify the traversal direction? If not, what are some good alternatives? Much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'd like to further clarify my situation. I have tried:

```
db.users.find({ customFields: { $elemMatch: { key: 'position' } } })
  .sort({ 'customFields.key': 1, 'customFields.value': 1 })

db.users.find({ customFields: { $elemMatch: { key: 'position' } } })
  .sort({'customFields.value': 1 })
```

These two queries only sort the documents **after** they have been filtered, meaning the sorting is applied on all the custom fields they have, not on the field matching the query (`position` in this case). So it seems using the `sort` method won't be of any help.

Not using any sorting conveniently returns the documents in the correct order in the ascending case. As can be seen in the explain result:

```
"direction" : "forward",
"indexBounds" : {
  "customFields.key" : [
    "[\"position\", \"position\"]"
  ],
  "customFields.value" : [
    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
   ]
 }
```

I'm using exact match for `customFields.key` so I don't care about it's order. Within each value of `customFields.key`, the values of `customFields.value` are arranged in the order specified in the index, so I just take them out as it is and all is good. Now if I could do something like:

```
db.users.find({ customFields: { $elemMatch: { key: 'position' } } })
  .direction('backwards')
```

It would be the equivalent of using the index `{ 'customFields.key': -1, 'customFields.value': -1 }`. Like I said I don't care about `customFields.key` order, and `'customFields.value': -1` gives me exactly what I want. I've searched mongodb documentation but I couldn't find anything similar to that.

I could retrieve all the documents matching `customFields.key` and do the sorting myself, but it's expensive as the number of documents could get very big. Ideally all the filtering and sorting is solved by the index.

Comment: you have crated index in ascending order, create index in descending order `{ 'customFields.key': -1, 'customFields.value': -1}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the compound index you created:

```js
db.users.createIndex( { "customFields.key": 1, "customFields.value": 1 } )
```

This index will allow traversal either using both fields in ascending order:

```
db.users.sort( { "customFields.key": 1, "customFields.value": 1 } )
```

Or, it can also support traversal using both keys in *descending* order:

```
db.users.sort( { "customFields.key": -1, "customFields.value": -1 } )
```

If you need mixed behavior, i.e. ascending on one field but descending on the other, then you would need to add a second index:

```
db.users.createIndex( { "customFields.key": 1, "customFields.value": -1 } )
```

Note that after adding this second index, all four possible combinations are now supported.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the answer. I've edited my question to explain my question in more details.